# AS3 - using variable inside a function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, function

I'm new in as3. I'm trying to use variable which i assign a value from a function. But the variable outside the function always shown as a null value. I tried using the global variable way, but seems not working too.

```
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
function loadComplete(event:Event)
{
   // Save Kongregate API reference
   kongregate = event.target.content;


   // Connect to the back-end
   kongregate.services.connect();


   // You can now access the API via:

   // kongregate.user
   // kongregate.scores
   // kongregate.stats
   // etc...
   username = kongregate.services.getUsername();
   trace("inside:"+username);


}

trace("outside:"+username);
```

How to use the variable a outside the function?
The output:

outside:
Alert: Kongregate API shadow services loaded due to local testing. API will load when the game is uploaded.
Kongregate API: IKongregateServices.connect() 
inside:Guest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function is called asynchronously. This means that the data you're trying to access isn't available until that `loadComplete` function is called, which could be at any time in the application flow.

[This article](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS948100b6829bd5a6-4c2e64612754b0a95b-8000.html) will explain asynchronous events in more detail.

Comment: the code i posted is just an example. i did call the function

Comment: @Ricky Can you post *exactly* what you have? Because what you're telling me should work fine.

Comment: done. what should i do so that the trace outside the function show the same value as inside the function?

Comment: @Ricky Ah see, that is a completely different situation.

Comment: hmm i see.. any suggestion how to solve this? or should i post new question? thanks for the response by the way

Comment: @Ricky Solve it in what way? You need to wait for that `loadComplete` function to be called before you can access the data, that's the *only* way to do it. I updated my answer as well.

Comment: @Marty 20,000 exactly, trusted user - well deserved.

Comment: Thanks @JasonSturges, hoping to see you up here soon as well :-) By the way I like your personal website.